# changing a Hex string at runtime

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

Lets say I have 0xFF222222 and would like it to reach 0xFF888888 over 5 minutes.
Using Java (android) what would be the simplest way to make it change?

RGB must stay equal throughout, meaning 0xFF222222 -> 0xFF232323 -> 0xFF242424 ...

Comment: Or I could just do it myself thanks. I have never needed to change and HEX value before now, other then what I define it pre-runtime. I know how to call and track time as it elapses, I just did not know how to edit the hex number itself at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer task to add 0x10101 on each execution until you reach 0xFF888888

Chances are you don't actually want a string, but a numeric value such as an int - though if you do want a string, it's easy to do the work with an int and use Integer.toHexString() to convert the result when needed.

Comment: You are correct, I think I do want an int, so I can do an operation such as `int i = 0xFF888888; int a = 0x101010; i = i + a;` ?

Comment: Yes, most of the android color methods want an int.  You may want to keep in mind that as (signed) ints these numbers are all negative - comparisons between them should still work, so it shouldn't really have an impact as long as you don't make any assumptions that they are positive.

Comment: To convert to that format, it would be easier to use `String.printf("0x%08X", value)` rather than Integer.toHexString() (which will not generate leading zeroes 8 significant digits).